# Accessing functions of another class without referencing in every instance?

Tags: python, last.fm

In the code below the `User` class needs to access a function `get_user` inside an instance of    `WebService` class, as that contains other functions required for authentication with the web server (last.fm). Actual code is [here](https://github.com/randomchars/pyfm).

```
class WebService:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.apikey = key

    def get_user(self, name):
        pass # Omitted

class User:

    def __init__(self, name, webservice):
        self.name = name
        self.ws = webservice

    def fill_profile(self):
        data = self.ws.GetUser(self.name)
        # Omitted
```

The problem is that a reference needs to be held inside every ´User´. Is there another way of doing this? Or is it just me overcomplicating things, and this is how it actually works in the real world?

Comment: Why is `fill_profile` in User?  Seems like it would make more sense to have a UserFactory that calls the service (or just processes a service response) and returns a User.

Comment: Get user can return an object too I just put the actual logic of populating the attributes inside it because it seemed to me that `User` would need to process data anyway since there're other functions (like `get_top_albums` and `get_friends`) Should every function like this get it's own individual class too?

Comment: I second @gilesc in having GetUser return a User.  As to handling things like get_top_albums and get_friends, that depends on how you want to model the system.  If you don't want to cache the data locally, I'd say just call the service each time with a user ID.  If you do want to cache the data locally, you could pass a User object to the method in WebService, then have the method populate the members of the User.  You do have to make a design decision though to either have a WebService and a User (what would probably be best), or just a UserWebService.

Comment: (Oops --accidental early submit before!)

The other way of doing this is to use User as purely a data object and let WebService do any work that requires the WebService. I.e., User.get_friends() becomes WebService.get_friends(User). Likewise User.fill_profile is just merged into WebService.get_user (no need for a UserFactory; WebService IS the UserFactory).

Comment: @sr2222 It seems like offloading every data generation to `WebService`   is the best call here. Could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:
As to handling things like get_top_albums and get_friends, that depends on how you want to model the system. If you don't want to cache the data locally, I'd say just call the service each time with a user ID. If you do want to cache the data locally, you could pass a User object to the method in WebService, then have the method populate the members of the User. You do have to make a design decision though to either have a WebService and a User (what would probably be best), or just a UserWebService.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly make the reference [a static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python), if the web service object is the same for all users.

The syntax is:

```
class User:
    webservice = ...
...
```

You will then even be able to access it from `User` instances, but not to assign to it that way, that would require `User.webservice` syntax.

You are also getting good design alternatives suggested in the comments.